# Get FTP directory content issue if it's empty

Tags: c#, directory, ftpwebrequest

I have code what gets a content of some FTP directory. At some servers I've tested it works fine.

But at one server this method throws an exception when we try to get response.

```
public static List<string> ListDirectory(string dirPath, string ftpUser, string ftpPassword)
    {
        List<string> res = new List<string>();

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(dirPath);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            res.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();

        return res;
    }
```

At catch section I have something like this

```
catch (WebException e)
{
   FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)e.Response;
   /*in my case response.Status = ActionNotTakenFileUnavailableOrBusy*/
   ....
}
```

It works before but now it fails when folder is empty. If there is something there it works. And I can see this directory with TotalCommander.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you allowed to use an external library instead of built in classes?

Comment: Yes, I allowed. But it will need a lot of changes.

Comment: OK I will add an example using the free System.Net.FtpClient available from CodePlex. Tell me if you could use it or not

Comment: Did you figure out why that was not working?

Comment: no, I recreated that code

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how to get a listing of a remote directory using the free library [System.Net.FtpClient](http://netftp.codeplex.com/) available from CodePlex.
I have used it in many occasions and, in my opinion, is more easy to work with

```
public void GetListing() 
{
    using (FtpClient conn = new FtpClient()) 
    {
        conn.Host = "your_ftp_site_url";
        conn.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("your_user_account", "your_user_password");
        foreach (FtpListItem item in conn.GetListing(conn.GetWorkingDirectory(),  FtpListOption.Modify | FtpListOption.Size)) 
        {
              switch (item.Type) 
              {
                    case FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory:
                        Console.WriteLine("Folder:" + item.Name);
                        break;
                    case FtpFileSystemObjectType.File:
                        Console.WriteLine("File:" + item.Name);
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the [download from this pages](http://netftp.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately I have exception that "path is correct but no answer". It seems that the same issue as before